# Owner of the directory for the mounted device

Tags: 18.04, mount, usb-drive

I have a USB drive with FAT32 file system. When I connect it to a VM with Ubuntu 18.04, it is mounted to the directory with the root owner, and I have problems writing to this USB-drive.

When I connect the USB drive to a VM with Ubuntu 20.04, it is mounted to the directory with the `$USER` owner, and I have no problems writing to this USB-drive.

Can I mount a USB drive in a directory owned by `$USER` in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

You can mount it with `-o uid=<username>`.

For example, if your the partition you want to mount is `/dev/sda1`, you want to mount it at `/mnt` and your username is `roman` you can mount it using:

```
sudo mount -o uid=roman /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Comment: In both cases, the usb drive is mounted automatically. But at 18.04, I can't write to a usb drive. Can I configure Ubuntu 18.04 to automatically mount a usb-drive to a directory owned by $USER ?